# php namespaces conflicting with composer namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php

In my project I have a folder for modules where they can have composer packages
The `namespace` for the module I'm making is Modules\View\View for Modules/View/View.php file

this is the directory layout

```
Modules
-View
--View.php
--vendor
---autoload.php
```

when I do this in View.php

```
public function __construct(){
    require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
    $this->loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('design');
    $this->twig = new Twig_Environment($this->loader);
}
```

I get an error:
**Fatal error: Class 'Modules\View\Twig_Loader_Filesystem' not found in Modules/View/View.php on line 12**

So I assumed this is because the View.php file has a namespace and I went to /Modules/View/vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php and changed

```
'Twig_' => array($vendorDir . '/twig/twig/lib')
```

to

```
'Modules\View\Twig_' => array($vendorDir . '/twig/twig/lib')
```

and it still doesn't work, however I'm still 100% sure it's because of the `namespace` because if you try to load it in a file without a `namespace` it works but as soon as you add it it gives that error

Answer (score 1):

*What is the namespace of Twig_Loader_Filesystem?*

If it does not have a namespace, you can load it using the root namespace (`\`):

```
$this->loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem('design');
```

You can also use the `use` keyword:

```
namespace Modules\View;

use Twig_Loader_Filesystem;
use Twig_Environment;

class View {

  public function __construct(){
    require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
    $this->loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('design');
    $this->twig = new Twig_Environment($this->loader);
  }

}
```